# Ignore / prevent emit of a particular file in wepack

Tags: webpack-2

Is there a way to prevent a specific file from being emitted to the output in Webpack (2)?

I'm using `html-webpack-plugin` and when building for the backend CMS, I'd like to avoid emitting the html file but still emit its meta image dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

this might help: [ignore-emit-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-emit-webpack-plugin)

it allows you to ignore emitted files by patterns

```
// webpack config
const IgnoreEmitPlugin = require('ignore-emit-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ... 
  plugins: [ new IgnoreEmitPlugin(/unwanted-file\.html$/) ]
  // ... 
};
```

disclosure - i'm the author